# Hyperlinking Access db to ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, ms-access, hyperlink

I am trying to hyperlink from MS Access to ArcMap to view specific features.  Within MS Access, I have 1400+ lines catalogued.  I would like to click a button and view the line in ArcMap.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Don't use Access?

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you import the MS tables into a Geodatabase?  Linking from a static MS database table may not produce the results you are looking for, as you will need/want to load the data (maybe multiple data layers) and open it into ArcMap.  You may also what to symbolize these layers.  If you are planning on viewing this in ArcMap, why not build a MXD project and bring in the tables.  You could also link the spatial features to the MS database table.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Command27_Click() Dim strAddress As String Dim strLink As String On Error GoTo myErr

    strAddress = Me.SURF_LATITUDE & "," & Me.SURF_LONGITUDE
    strLink = "https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?find="
    Application.FollowHyperlink strLink & strAddress

On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub myErr:
    Resume Next End Sub
```

Comment: Please, [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/258208/edit) your answer and explain what you want to say. Your answer is incomprehensible